# Errno111 Connection Refused Kivy Socket Error

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I am a new beginner in kivy I am developing a app that connect to my windows pc using python sockets

This is my Kivy App code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import socket

class FloatLay(FloatLayout):
    def Connect(self):
        try:
            s = socket.socket()
            hostname = '127.0.0.1'
            port = 8080
            s.connect((hostname, port))
        except Exception as e:
            self.ids.text.text = str(e)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloatLay()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

This is my .kv kivy file

```
<FloatLay>:
    Button:
        text:"Connect"
        pos_hint:{"x":0.6,"top":0.5}
        size_hint:0.1,0.05
        on_press: root.Connect()
    Label:
        id:text
        text:"Connect Status"
        pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"top":0.5}
        size_hint:0.4,0.05
```

This is my Socket_Server

```
import socket
def main():
 while True:
    running=False
    listensocket = socket.socket() 
    Port = 8080 
    maxConnections = 999
    IP = '127.0.0.1' #IP address of local machine
    listensocket.bind((IP,Port))
    listensocket.listen(maxConnections)
    print("Server started at " + IP + " on port " + str(Port))
    (clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()
    print("New connection made!")

    running = True
    try:
        while running:
            message = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
            print(message)
    except:
        print('')
main()
```

Whenever I run the code their is a error named Connection Refused

I dont think their is a mistake in my code as when i run the Client code and the Server on my windows pc at the same time they both are connected.

> Note:I am running the App on a android device and the code on a
> windows pc

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for adding your code, can yo explain which part of this application is not working?  What error messages are you recieving or what symptoms are you observing that indicate it is not working?  Also, since you are what version of android are you running under?

Comment: In addition, what version of python is running on the android as well as what version of python is running on server?

Comment: @itprorh66 I am receiving an error that says [Errno111] Connection Refused as you can see in the code I have used a Label to display the code the main problem is that the client or the app is not getting connected to the server on a windows pc I have also tried to use the server on ubuntu VM but everytime its the same error. I am using Android Version 10.

Comment: The server is running on python 3.8.5 and I have converted my kivy script to apk using buildozer which again I had used python 3.8.5

Comment: Are you using `127.0.0.1` in your android app? If so, that won't work as `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address, and you would be trying to connect the android device to itself. You need the address of the server.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thanks for your responce, but I have already solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for this if you are using windows then follow these steps:

1. Open command prompt
2. Type `ipconfig`
3. Find the IPv4 in `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi` section
4. Copy it and paste your IPv4 as a string to the IP vairable.

> Note: Dont add any spaces while typing the IP